# jQuery image slideshow that fades back to the first image after being stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I am trying to build an image slideshow that fades back to the first image after stopping it, but I don't get it. Would anyone be so kind to point me towards a solution?

Here's the code: http://codepen.io/peterschmidler/pen/hFHtJ

Thanks a lot!

PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJFcj

```
if (context.hasClass("stopshow")) {
   next = context.find('.images img:first');  
   stopshow = true;
}else{
   next = next.length ? next : context.find('.images img:first');
}
```

Here we're just checking to see if the class `stopshow` is present, and using a simple `if` statement to manipulate our assignment of `next`.

Then in the animation callback, we only repeat if the `stopshow` variable is not true

```
if(!stopshow) filesCrossfade(context)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now there's only one bug left. When I hit Stop while the first image is fading in again, it fades out on top of the background and then fades in again. Got a solution for that, too? It would be great!

Comment: @PeterSchmidler - I sure do. I've updated the pen. You can save the previous index and check it.

Comment: Is there any way to define the prev var inside the function?

Comment: @PeterSchmidler - have updated again. We don't actually need the `prev` var, we can use the `index()` of `active` and `next` as a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Why re-invent the wheel? Try the well known jQuery cycle slideshow plugin. It is lightweight, works on mobile devices, is very easy to implement, and has many very useful customisation options. See [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function filesCrossfade(context) {
    if (context.hasClass("stopshow")) {
      context.find('.images img.active').removeClass('active').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
      context.find('.images img:first').addClass('active').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
      return;

    }

    if (context.find('.images img').length > 1) {

      var active = context.find('.images img.active');
      var next = active.next();
      next = next.length ? next : context.find('.images img:first');
      active.removeClass('active').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
      next.addClass('active').delay(500).fadeIn(500, function() {
        filesCrossfade(context) });

    }

  }

  $(".content .slideshow").each(function(){
    $(this).find('.images img').hide();
    $(this).find('.images img').eq(0).fadeIn(500);

  });

  filesCrossfade($(".content .slideshow").eq(0));

  $('.stop').click(function(){
    $(".content .slideshow").eq(0).addClass("stopshow");
  });  

});
```

Comment: Thanks, too! Your solution has the same bug as ahren's. When I hit Stop while the first image is fading in again, it fades out to white (background) and then fades in again. Any clue how to get rid of that? PS